# New Ubuntu version on old device

Tags: ubuntu, kernel

I have an old device (tv box) with Android 4.4.2 (kernel 3.0.x), and I've found an old version of Ubuntu with some kernel that runs fine.
But this old version is more outdated, and it is not usable.

The Question:
Is it possible to recompile a new version of Ubuntu from `.config` file extract from the working Ubuntu?

Comment: Did you _try_ with a newer release of Ubuntu? It's not clear why you started with an old release.

Comment: Yes, i want to try a newest version, I've try an old version because it is the only I've found.  Are version that work on sdcard, without installations